# difference between v-model and :model-value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I wanted to ask, because it's still hard for me to understand what is the difference between
`v-model` and `:model-value`
In the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), I read that:
`v-model is used on a native element:`

```
<input v-model="searchText" />
```

but, when I use on a component, `v-model` instead expands to this:

```
<CustomInput
  :modelValue="searchText"
  @update:modelValue="newValue => searchText = newValue"
/>
```

And ok, I understand that. But sometimes I see, that in custom components we still using:

```
    <CustomInput
     v-model="searchText" // => why v-model, not :model-value
     @update:modelValue="newValue => searchText = newValue"
   />
```

So I'm a confused a little bit, about why, and what is the difference between this two options.

Comment: The question contains incorrect premises. "we still using" - who's we? The example is badly written code. Generally it's either one or another.

Comment: I guess there is NO runtime difference (except second one being bad cod)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on Vue.js documentation ([link](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html)):

> v-model can be used on a component to implement a two-way binding.

`:prop` is the shortcut for `v-bind`.
for example:
`<BlogPost :title="post.title" />` is exactly the same as `<BlogPost v-bind:title="post.title" />`

on custom components `v-model` is just a shortcut for:

```
  :modelValue="value"
  @update:modelValue="newValue => value = newValue"
```

and on a native component `v-model` is just a shortcut for:

```
  :modelValue="value"
  @input="newValue => event => value = event.target.value"
```

([digitalocean on v-model](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-v-model-two-way-binding))

as you see unlike `v-bind`, `v-model` allows for changing the value from inside the child component.
so if you use 'v-model' the line `@update:modelValue="newValue => searchText = newValue"` can be removed.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

In your exact case there is no difference, the same value just gets assigned twice.

This, hovewer, may make sence if the listener is not the same as just assignement:

```js
    <CustomInput
     // same as  
     // :modelValue="searchText" @update:modelValue="v => searchText = v"
     v-model="searchText"
     // second listener for the same event
     @update:modelValue="newValue => console.log('got', newValue)"
   />
```

---

[playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!\n')

const n = ref(123)

watch(n, () => { msg.value += `n has updated to ${n.value}\n` })

function update(v) {
  msg.value += `update was called with ${v}\n`
}

</script>

<template>
  <Comp v-model="n" type="number" @update:model-value="update" />
  <br>
  <textarea v-model="msg" rows=30 cols=70></textarea>
<!-- 
Hello World!
update was called with 124
n has updated to 124
update was called with 125
n has updated to 125
update was called with 126
n has updated to 126
update was called with 127
-->
</template>
```